# KQL Timechart Render of Two Lines to Analyze for Anomalies

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

newbie here!!

Based on the following KQL query, I am trying to render two lines based on Type (either AADNonInteractiveUserSignInLogs or BehaviorAnalytics):

```
AADNonInteractiveUserSignInLogs
| project TimeGenerated, Type, UserPrincipalName
| union (BehaviorAnalytics | project TimeGenerated, Type, UserPrincipalName)
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(120d)
| where UserPrincipalName contains "USER_HERE"
```

However, if I simply add the following:

```
| summarize count() by Type, bin(TimeGenerated, 1d)
| render timechart
```

I will get the following result: [two lines render together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78YYz.png)

My goal is to see both lines pattern overlapping each other to analyze for anomalies.

Top line [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcv7W.png)

Bottom line: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihXOW.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate percentage per row for all the values on the count column as below so that the value to compare is on percentage. This will help in analysis of the data like you expected.

I have used sample data and tried below query.

**Query**

```
let tbl1 = AzureMetrics
|summarize Count_AM = count()
by MetricName,
bin(TimeGenerated, 3d) | as AM
|extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Count_AM / toscalar(AM | summarize sum(Count_AM)));
let tbl2 = AzureDiagnostics 
| summarize Count_AD= count() by MetricName = SubscriptionId , bin(TimeGenerated,3h) | as AD
|extend Percentage = round(100.0 * Count_AD / toscalar(AD | summarize sum(Count_AD)));
tbl1 | union (tbl2)
| project-away Count_AD,Count_AM
| render timechart
```

**Result**

[image]